# How can I draw a vegetation profile on ArcMap or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, cartography, elevation, profile

I have two layers: elevation (raster) and vegetation map (polygons). I would like to generate an elevation profile with a line that besides having the elevation form, appears the length of the different vegetation polygons. Something similar to the image I attach below, without the trees, but having a line reflecting different polygons and colors as in that image they have the categories "stream bed, stream banks, flats, etc.".

I tried the tool interpolate line but I'm only able to get the elevation line, not the different colors according to the type of vegetation. Is this possible with ArcMap or QGIS?

[image]

Comment: This might give you some ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372754/elevation-profile-with-labels-on-waypoints-qgis-python

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please embed images in the Question directly, rather than as a link that best security practice insists shouldn't be followed. The current build of ArcGIS is 10.8.1. There's a great deal of functionality that has been added since 10.1, but it seems likely *something* could be done to accomplish this with an archaic release. Please [Edit] the question to state what have you tried, and where are you stuck.