# Calculate slope along line feature for line segments of equal elevation?

Tags: qgis, slope, terrain

I would like to calculate the surface slope of a glacier in the Swiss alps.

In ArcGIS Pro this can be done using the *Add Surface Information Tool*. The output is a data table with the slope for each line segment (line is segmented in equal elevation differences, not equal length).

As I want my work to be accessible for all, I want to perform the same analysis in QGIS. So far I used the *qProf tool*. However, as I understand it qProf is splitting the line into segments of equal length and not into segments of equal elevation differences.

Is there any other method, or tool to perform the analysis? So far I only found solutions for segments of equal lengths.

I am using a layer with a line feature for the glacier centerlines and a DEM raster.

The output I want to create is a topographic profile along the glacier centerlines (see first picture)[image]

[image: calculate slope along centerlines (pink) for DEM25_grid_raster]

Comment: Are you asking how to vectorize the results of the `slope` tool and then intersect this vector layer with your lines?

Comment: Would this give me a topographic profile along the lines?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but maybe this can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372754/elevation-profile-with-labels-on-waypoints-qgis-python/372757#372757

Comment: The first version of the question didn't mention profiles @Flexalo. Anyway, check the `profile tool` plugin.