# Create a profile of categorical data along a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, profile

For a landscape analysis study, I want to extract some categorical data along a line (purple in the image) on the selected area. Before I continue to create an entire plugin to create a categorical "profile", maybe it has already been done. I will explain the situation below.

[image: the selected area outlined in blue with the profile line in purple projected over the information in the vector-layer]

Along this line I can already obtain a height profile (via elevation profile or profile tool), but would like to add "profiles" of categorical data (from a vector-layer with polygons), as horizontal bars below the height profile.

[image: example of a categorical data "profile" below a height profile as extracted from the shown vector-data]

In order to produce these bars, I already took steps to find the positions of intersections for a vector layer using `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Polygons to Lines` followed by `Vector -> Analysis Tools -> Line Intersections`. It would then be possible to write some code to determine which polygon/category is covered in which part of the profile, but maybe someone has already done this.

[image: the selected area where the polygons have been reduced to lines, and the intersections with the profile-line shown]

Before I continue to create an entire plugin to make these charts:

1. What would you name such a categorical "profile"?
2. Is a plugin for creating these already available?

Comment: I'm sure you can do something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372754/elevation-profile-with-labels-on-waypoints-qgis-python) and [color by y value](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/color_by_yvalue.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-color-by-yvalue-py)

Comment: @BERA, thank you for your look into the question, but since my data is categorical, and not a DEM / height map, I do not directly see how to apply the examples you provided.