# Elevation Profile with labels on waypoints using QGIS, Map Atlas, Python, Highcharts and HTML

Tags: pyqgis, html, profile, elevation-profile

I am seeking assistance with @Christoph's very clever answer / suggested solution to [Elevation Profile with labels on waypoints using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372754) on how to show labels in a QGIS Highcharts elevation profile.

This would be a very elegant solution if I could display the generated elevation profile with labels using python, Highcharts and an HTML frame when generating a QGIS Map Atlas.

I have been able to follow all @Christoph's suggested steps, including using python to generate the waypoints virtual layer with relevant fields and data, setting up the qgis macro, setting up and generating a map atlas.

However I am falling over with the html frame. Setting up the html frame all seems fine but when preview the atlas, I cant generate the profile .

Comment: you could try to copy the Highcharts JavaScript files to a local server or look for a different library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Christoph. Was hoping to troubleshoot why I cant get your helpful example to work. The highcharts library should be able to do all I need it do. having worked through all your steps, its the last step of displaying the chart that is failing. Everything else generates results in accordance with your example except the htmlframe with highcharts html remains blank at the last step. Am sure is something simple. Thanks anyway.